# Error shown while extracting og:image from database on homepage in php?

Tags: php, mysql, database, facebook

I've extracted og image to be seen on facebook share from mysql database. The below code has worked but only problem is that it shows an error: `" />`  on the top of my homepage.

How can I remove this `" />` sign from my home page? Have I done any mistake on this code?

Any guidance for my problem is appreciated.

```
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <?php
    $fetch_sql = "SELECT fld_news_pictures,  fld_news_name, fld_news_details FROM tbl_news ";
    $fetch_result= mysql_query($fetch_sql) or die(mysql_error()); 
    while($fetch_row=mysql_fetch_array($fetch_result))
    {
    $fld_news_name = $fetch_row['fld_news_name'];
    $fld_news_pictures = $fetch_row['fld_news_pictures'];
    $fld_news_details = $fetch_row['fld_news_details'];
    ?>
    <meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $fld_news_name; }?>" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://mysite/images/<?php echo $fld_news_pictures; ?>" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo $fld_news_details } ?>" />
```

Comment: Check your php echo, you have a `}` that I think should not be there, in the first and last echo. Also, the last one is missing a `;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edited:** You have an extra brace inside your `og:title` tag `}?>` which should be removed. That should have thrown a parse error using error reporting.

- Also make sure the file does have a `.php` extension.

By the way, `mysql_` functions are deprecated and will be removed in PHP 7.0

Get used to using `mysqli_` or PDO with prepared statements.

Plus, it is unknown as to which MySQL API you're using to connect with. As per what you posted, it should be `mysql_` and not `mysqli_` or PDO. Those different APIs do not intermix.

- However, you should be using `mysqli_` or PDO nowadays and then convert your entire code to a more recent API.

Rewrite: (placed inside `<head></head>` of your document)

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<?php
$fetch_sql = "SELECT fld_news_pictures,  fld_news_name, fld_news_details FROM tbl_news ";
$fetch_result= mysql_query($fetch_sql) or die(mysql_error()); 
while($fetch_row=mysql_fetch_array($fetch_result))
{
$fld_news_name = $fetch_row['fld_news_name'];
$fld_news_pictures = $fetch_row['fld_news_pictures'];
$fld_news_details = $fetch_row['fld_news_details'];
?>
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $fld_news_name; ?>" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://mysite/images/<?php echo $fld_news_pictures; ?>" />
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo $fld_news_details; ?>" /> <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Might want to close the while loop after the `meta`s. As is will only have 1 name/picture/detail. Not sure if that can appear multiple times and/or if there actually are multiple records.

Comment: @chris85 I feel you're right about this and this should call for some tricky *in and out* of PHP method which I always get wrong. I thought the variables assignment in the `while` loop would take care of that, no? or, there's a missing brace somewhere.

Comment: The variables will only have the last row's data currently. I think `}` should be after `og:description` element.

Comment: @chris85 Thanks, I've made an edit. I hope I got it right lol - I can never get used to those funny loops.

Comment: Yea, the crossing back and forth I never like. I usually set it to arrays then output iterate through later when needed. Your gonna need a separate PHP block for the closing. As is the last meta won't be closed.

Comment: @chris85 Same here. I never use that type of syntax myself because it just confuses me; always has, always will. If I may; what do you think of the edit I made, does that seem to pan out?

Comment: Potentially not, the `} ?>" />` will iterate through the loop then output the `/>` after. So there will be x number of `og:description` `meta`s without their closing. If there is only one record though this will work fine. Should be `<?php echo $fld_news_details; ?>" /> <?php } ?>`

Comment: @chris85 Thanks again Chris, I made the edit. *Crossing fingers*. Cheers, I appreciate the help on this.

Comment: @chris85 Yes, you are absolutely correct. Closing the while loop after metatag worked. <?php echo $fld_news_details; ?>" /> <?php } ?>  Thanks a lot...

Comment: @Jklyn Consider accepting this answer if it helped in resolving your issue `;-)` cheers.